# Could not convert brace enclosed initializer list for std::pair in std::map

Tags: c++11, stdmap, std-pair

I have the following setup:

```
typedef std::function<void()> reaction;

class Node
{
  public:
  ...

  private:
    void connect();
    void receive();

  private:
    const std::map<std::pair<Status, Event>, reaction> TransTable = {
      {{DISCONNECTED, CONNECT}, &Node::connect},
      {{CONNECTING, RECEIVE}, &Node::receive}
    };
}
```

But I always get the error:

```
error: could not convert from <brace-enclosed initializer list> to const std::map<std::pair<Status, Event>, std::function<void()> >
```

What is wrong with my initalizer list?

Comment: what is "reaction"? it's not defined so the error comes from this.

Comment: Sorry forgot to include it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is missing a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), however the error message is clear enough: `reaction` seems to be a typedef for `std::function<void()>`. A member function pointer such as `&Node::connect` cannot be converted to a `std::function<void()>`, because the latter lacks any kind of `this` parameter upon which to actually call the function.

You can, however, use lambdas to capture and store the instance that is currently initializing this `TransTable` member:

```
const std::map<std::pair<Status, Event>, reaction> TransTable = {
  {{DISCONNECTED, CONNECT}, [this] { connect(); }},
  {{CONNECTING,   RECEIVE}, [this] { receive(); }}
};
```